# How to avoid table scan and index scan for huge tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using MSSQL 2008 R2.  I have a table with huge number of rows (test table)

I have the following SQL code, please suggest where I can use index hints, force seek or any other means to improve performance.

Indexes
 1. non-clustered - `idx_id` (id)
 2. non-clustered - `idx_name` (name)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.id,
    p.name,
FROM 
    test p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            e.id 
        FROM 
            test e  
            INNER JOIN
            ( 
                SELECT 
                    c.id 
                FROM 
                    test c 
                GROUP BY 
                    c.id 
                HAVING 
                    COUNT(1) > 1 
            ) f 
            ON e.id = f.id
        WHERE 
            e.name = 'test_name'
    ) m 
    ON p.id = m.id
WHERE 
    m.id is null
```

Comment: Could you indent your query a little? It almost looks like obfuscated code as it is.

Comment: Can you show us the query plan?

Comment: novice here , unable to indent , i tried and not able to provide execution plan but, all used is index scan and one table scan on left outer join table p

Comment: What is your Primay Key? ID isn't unique?

Comment: there are few more column in select list but i have showun only two of them and there is composite priomary key and its not useful as i am not selecting data for those columns

Comment: The PK is usefull. Check my query.

Comment: @Serge - Thanks for your answer, but its doesnt suit my structure and cant change it. i need help on index hints , where to use what to use

Comment: How doesn't it suit your structure? You said you had a PK.

Comment: Please provide more details: what you've already tried and why, maybe ask a more specific question. SO's format is Q&A, not "help me solve my problem."

Answer (score 1):

Prerequise: have a primary key

```
select distinct
    p.id
    , p.name
from test p 
where not exists (
    SELECT TOP(1)
        1
    FROM test e
    WHERE e.PrimaryKey <> p.PrimaryKey
    AND  e.id = p.id
    AND 'test_name' IN (e.name, p.name)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

How many columns your table contains? If there's only these two columns, it makes no sense to add nonclustered index. You should create CLUSTERED index on ID column, and that's it - you'll see performance increase.

If you have many colums, consider two options:

1. Create clustered index on NAME column and nonclustered index on ID column.
2. Create nonclustered index on ID column, and INCLUDE NAME column (you'll create covering index that way)

Comment: there are few more column in select list but i have showun only two of them and there is composite priomary key and its not useful as i am not selecting data for those columns

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, relational databases (being relational) are written in such a way to optimize join statements.  When using a "JOIN" clause with "ON" criteria, the database engine can create an optimized execution plan that takes the table structure, indexes, etc. into account.  When joining on a sub-select, sometimes the same optimizing factors are not available, or are not taken into account the same way.  It depends on your schema, but it is a good rule of thumb to assume that ***a standard join with an "on" clause is going to be more efficient than a join on a sub-select***.

Your schema is pretty vague, so I am not even sure that you need the joins, but if you do, you should try performing the joins directly with "on" criteria.